# Joining 2 sas tables and repeating the second values as much as they correspond to the common value in the first table

Tags: join, datatable, sas

I have 2 SAS datasets and in the first table I have for example (table_1):

```
Period IPC
201801 24
201801 45
201801 10
201801 20
201802 17
201802 18
201802 32
```

In the second table we have for example (table_2) :

```
Period CaR
201801 11
201802 49
```

the goal is to have a data set that will be like (table_3):

```
Period IPC CaR
201801  24  11
201801  45  11
201801  10  11
201801  20  11
201802  17  49
201802  18  49
201802  32  49
```

I have tryed:

```
data table_3;
    merge table_1 (in=a) 
          table_2(in=b);
    by Periode;

    if a then output;
run;
```

But it didn't work.

the error is:

```
ERROR: By variable are not properly sorted on data set table_1
warning: the data set table_3 may be incomplete. when this step was stopped there were 95 observations and 114 variables.
```

Any help would be very apreciated :)

Comment: What didn't work about it?  Other than the typo, I hope, what did you get in the result that you didn't like, or was there an error message?

Comment: @Joe thanks. I added the error to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the datasets are sorted before trying to merge them.

```
proc sort data=table_1 ;
  by Periode;
run;
proc sort data=table_2 ;
  by Periode;
run;

data table_3;
  merge table_1 (in=a) 
        table_2(in=b);
  by Periode;
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid having to sort you can also use proc sql to join instead:

```
proc sql;
   create table_3 as
   select    a.*
          ,  b.*
   from table_1 as a
   left join table_2 as b
      on a.period = b.period
   ;
quit;
```

Comment: Note you are not avoiding the sorting, just avoiding having to write the code to do the sorting.  SQL will do the sorting to enable it to do the join.

Comment: Sorry bad wording on my behalf, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @MartinShine. Thanks but it didn't work for me.

Comment: I think it might have been cause I used "period" rather than "periode", anyway both methods work.